# Which skill does Kills-in-Shadow use for Two-Handed Weapons?

Tags: tyranny

Kills-in-Shadow has two skills named "Untamed Might". The description reads:

> Increased one-handed melee weapon damage. (Kills-in-Shadow uses two-handed weapons as one-handed.)

The wording  on this makes me wonder if Kills-in-Shadow uses the one-handed skill or the two-handed skill for Two-Handed weapons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the developers (see [this](https://forum.paradoxplaza.com/forum/index.php?threads/untamed-might-ii-not-working.986277/#post-22172038)) she uses the one-handed skill for both one-handed and two-handed weapons.